# Sequelize how to include soft deleted records deletedAt

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to add a feature to un-soft-delete a user with

```
Users.update( { deletedAt: null }, { where: { userId: request.params.userId } });
```

This doesn't work as expected, and doesn't update record's deletedAt param to null

When I turn on logging I see the above, resolves to the below

> Executing (default): UPDATE `users` SET
>   `deletedAt`=NULL,`updatedAt`='2019-03-03 22:53:54' WHERE ((`deletedAt`
>   > '2019-03-03 22:53:54' OR `deletedAt` IS NULL) AND `userId` = 2174)

It seems the update statement is ignoring the item I want to un-delete, since it's deleted. Quite the conundrum eh..

How can I tell sequelize to also update deleted records? I've tried adding the `paranoid: false` flag but it doesn't seem to be a legal param in options for an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is `paranoid: false` :

**Try this one :**

```
Users.update( { deletedAt: null }, { where: { userId: request.params.userId } , paranoid: false  });
```

> **options.paranoid**
>
> If true, only non-deleted records will be updated. If false, both
>   deleted and non-deleted records will be updated. Only applies if
>   options.paranoid is true for the model.

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update)**

Comment: Dang! Thanks @Vivek ... in my original question I even wrote that I tried and it it doesn't work. TypeScript was telling me that was an invalid UpdateOption and erroring, and if you check that doc you linked to it doesn't even list paranoid under Update options ... yet it works exactly as expected when put in. Maybe my type def is the wrong version? Anyway that does it, thanks

Comment: Glad to here :)

Comment: @VivekDoshi we tried doing this to undo a soft delete but it looks like the raw sql shows the `deleted_at` is not part of the set clause, even with paranoid set to true, tho other values in the update command seem to be getting updated on the soft deleted object. Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Model.restore](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html#restoring) method for *un-soft-deleting*. Here's the [API doc](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-restore) for the full list of supported options.

Example:

```js
let { userId } = request.params;
await User.restore({ where: { userId } });
```